# Pandas dataframe, keeping values with the same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I guess the title is kinda confusing so let me show you first the data

`UserID                 appid           playtime
0  76561193665450065     10                26
1  76561193665450065     20                 0
2  76561193665450065     30                 0
3  76561193665450065     40                 0
4  76561193666198401     420                 3
5  76561193666198401    8190                64
6  76561193666198401   72850              8717`

So i want to make some calculations but i need to take one UserID per time and check his appid and playtime.

I need something like `df['UserID'][i]`

Due to request, the result that i want is

`UserID               appid           playtime
1  76561193665450065     10                26
                         20                 0
                         30                 0
                         40                 0
2  76561193665450446     40                48
                         110               20`

I dont know how many rows are in each UserID.
I want to select UserID and see all the appid that he has.

Comment: Show the results you re trying to get, it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: @boud Hope this helps

Comment: @ThodorisP, Does this work for you `grp = df.groupby('UserID');
grp.get_group(list(grp.groups.keys())[i])` where i is the iterator through the number of such groups of *UserID* present?(Syntax in Python 3)

Answer (score 0):

You could write as below:

```
df.ix[i, 'UserId']
```

If you want to choose multiple columns:

```
df.ix[0, ['UserId', 'appid']]
```

Comment: This doesnt recongize the next UserID

Answer (score 0):

If `UserID` is a simple column in your dataframe, use square brackets:

```
df[df.UserID == 76561193665450065]

              UserID  appid  playtime
0  76561193665450065     10        26
1  76561193665450065     20         0
2  76561193665450065     30         0
3  76561193665450065     40         0
```

If `UserID` is the index of your dataframe, use `.loc`:

```
df.set_index('UserID').loc[76561193665450065]

                   appid  playtime
UserID                            
76561193665450065     10        26
76561193665450065     20         0
76561193665450065     30         0
76561193665450065     40         0
```

Comment: I dont know the name of the UserID, there are 1million entries

Comment: I'm quoting you and referring to you example: "I want to select UserID and see all the appid that he has.". To select a user you need to know its value.

Comment: No. I had  done it before but dont remember how. There was the index, 0 1 2... and its index had only one user id , see the result example